# Possessive form of the noun...why is it incorrect?

Tags: gerunds, possessives, present-participles

> Jem could be malicious at times, as shown from Scout's explaining that
>   Jem was pure evil.

When I wrote this sentence, everyone said that I should not use the possessive form of "Scout" for some reason.

I thought that it doesn't matter whether I use it or not and that I am actually encouraged to use it, but they said that it just does not make sense.

I myself strongly believe that when the noun is followed by a gerund of any type, it is fine to change the noun to possessive form *if* the noun is not plural.

For instance: His being a foreigner made thing a little difficult.

So why are they saying it is incorrect usage? Or is it actually correct?

Comment: We, not being them, cannot really tell you why *they* are saying it is incorrect usage, can we?

Comment: More importantly, you should have an *-s* on the end of *at time**s*** and *made thing**s***, and you probably want to say *was pure evil* without ***a***.  Probably *as shown **by***, too.

Comment: Thank you. Also, I think as shown from is fine. Other than that, is using possessive form correct there?

Comment: Yeah, I don't mean to say that *as shown from* is actually wrong.  It's just that native speakers say and write *as shown by* far more often ([COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=41414052) - [BNC](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/?c=bnc&q=41414109) - [Google Books](https://goo.gl/XaQ3wf)).  But since *as shown from* isn't entirely unattested, I put 'probably' in my comment to weaken the assertion a little. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence is fine. Use of the possessive before the gerund is the usual rule English speakers learn. See [this example](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/gerundspro.html).  There is some debate about whether use of the possessive here is necessary (see [this blog entry](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2637) for more), but you are not incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I think since you used the preposition "from", which is *clearly* intended to apply to "explaining" (and not to "Scout"), the gerund "*explaining*" becomes the object.  You can hang any attributes/adjectives on it as you wish, and if you want to point out *whose* explaining it was, you need possessive.

Let's say, for the sake of argument, that you wanted to use a *participle clause*.  How would you do it?  Probably

> ..., as shown ***by*** Scout explaining that Jem...

Now, in that subclause you can use either possessive (genitive) or objective (accusative) with pretty much the same result.  With objective, the "explaining" is a *present participle*.  With possessive, it's a *gerund*.

---

Since the OP asked, here are two examples:

> **Fishing** is a great sport! - gerund
>   He spent his entire summer **fishing**. - participle

The main difference is what role they play.  Gerund plays the role of a noun.  Participle plays the role of an adjective or adverb (adverbial phrase).

Comment: I don't really see any difference between present participle and gerund. Can you give an example?

Comment: Since you used the preposition "from", the gerund "explaining" becomes the object. By this, do you mean that only "Scout's" can be used but not "Scout"? Only the possessive, but not the original form?

Comment: No, it's not necessarily limited to possessive.  But given that Scout is likely a creature, it's not idiomatic to say "as shown ***from*** Scout".  You can say "as Scout had shown", or "as Scout showed", or even "as Scout explained", or "as I heard ***from*** Scout".

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally understood what you were saying.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer earlier.

Comment: It's ok! I didn't mean to be sarcastic.